# Handling ClassCastException In Different Objects

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time to understand the ClassCastException and it is crashing the line that it is commented. Please explain why its doing in that? Thanks

```
public class tester {

    private static B<Data> build(char[] ss, double[] f) {

        B<Data> res = new B<Data>();

        PriorityQueue<String> q = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        ...
        double c_x = 20.1;

        Data h = res.getElement(); //throws ClassCastException

        if(h.getFreq()==c_x){
            ...
        }
    }//end of method
}//end of class tester

public class Data{

    private char symbol;
    private double freq;

    public Data(char c, double f){
        symbol = c;
        freq = f;
    }

    public char getSymbol(){
        return symbol;
    }

    public double getFreq(){
        return freq;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return freq + ":" + symbol;
    }

    public int compareTo(Data o) {
        return (int) (this.freq-o.freq);
    }
}//end of class Data

public class B<T> {

    // the fields
    private T element;
    private B<T> left;
        private B<T> right;

        // create an empty node
        public B() {
            this(null, null, null);
        }

        public B(T theElement, B<T> lt, B<T> rt) {
            element = theElement;
            left = lt;
            right = rt;
        }

        // return the element
        public T getElement() {
            return element;
        }
        public void setElement(T x) {
            element = x;
        }        

 }//end of class B
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to Data
at tester.build(tester.java:40)
at tester.main(tester.java:83)
```

Comment: Can you post what error message you get as well? Somehow a object that is not `Data` got into `res`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to Data
 at tester.build(tester.java:40)
 at tester.main(tester.java:83)                                                                           My line numbers are different than yours but it crashes.

Comment: your res.getElement() is a Double value not  Data object. Not sure what is B in this context. Can you check the getElement() implementation of B  and see what it is returning?

Comment: getElement is returning a T object (generic) which is Data in this case. I believe the getElement method works fine.

Comment: It's only a `T` if the collection is generified. You could've accidentally rawtyped it elsewheres in your code, but we can't know because somewhere between the creation of `res` and that error, you've omitted the issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post complete code I could run, I have to make my own.

Data.java:

```
package test;

public class Data {
    private char symbol;
    private double freq;

    public Data(char c, double f){
        symbol = c;
        freq = f;
    }

    public char getSymbol(){
        return symbol;
    }

    public double getFreq(){
        return freq;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return freq + ":" + symbol;
    }

    public int compareTo(Data o) {
        return (int) (this.freq-o.freq);
    }   
}
```

GenericType.java (replacing B):

```
package test;

public class GenericType<T> {
    private T element;

    public GenericType() {
        element = null;
    }

    public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(T x) {
        element = x;
    }        
}
```

Test.java (main program):

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericType<Data> obj = new GenericType<Data>();
        Data d = obj.getElement();      
        System.out.println("Data retrieved");
    }
}
```

When executed:

```
> java test.Test
Data retrieved
```

So there's a problem somewhere, and you omitted it.

How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Generics is only a compile-time concept. At runtime they are just Objects. Your problem most likely lies in how you instantiate B.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have some method that takes a raw type `B`? Because if you do, you can assign any value to `element` in that method.

**Example**

```
static void rawSet(B b) {
    b.setElement(1.0); // you can put anything here
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    B<Integer> b = new B<>();
    rawSet(b);
    Integer x = b.getElement(); // ClassCastException 
}
```